# How to calculate z score in python? For example I want to calculate z score of 1.0?

Tags: python

a = 1.0

how to calculate zscore of a variable?

I googled and got the function
zscore(arr, axis=0, ddof=0)

need help to understand as it takes array as parameter. Can someone write code and show me how the function is used. Please note that a is a normal variable in Python and not an array. The aim is to print Z score of variable a.

Comment: zscore needs the sample mean and standard deviation. it cannot be calculated on one sample value

Comment: Yes completely agree those are inputs. Below is the codeimport numpy as np 
from scipy import stats 

m=float(input())#mean
sd=float(input())#standard deviation

z = float((m-90)/sd)
a=[]
a.append(float((m-90)/sd))

print(a)

Answer (score 0):

Is it a real task or you trying to learn how to use zscore ?

As my understanding zscore is used with array of items and to find the standard deviation.

see below.. for an example.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scipy-stats-zscore-function-python/

Comment: import numpy as np 
from scipy import stats 

m=float(input())#mean
sd=float(input())#standard deviation

z = float((m-90)/sd)
a=[]
a.append(float((m-90)/sd))

print(a)

Comment: both sd and mean are provided please refer the program above